# Regex inside If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using Regex to get part of my text but I can't use the result as conditional statement. Even using `[1]` to select only the result after Regex, my condition can't work.

```
var dec = "> PRZ ##"   
var cursodec = /\>([^#>]+)\##/.exec(dec);
var cursodecl = cursodec[1];

if (cursodecl == "PRZ") {
...
}
```

Any solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: can you share more info like 1) what is `dec`? 2) what is your regex suppose to do?

Comment: Done! My Regex get the "PRZ" inside dec.

Comment: Looks to me like your regex sub group will include the space characters on either side of PRZ, and thus cursodec will be `" PRZ "`.  Have your tried `console.log(cursodec)` to confirm the results?

Comment: Only here (SO) I have the space, not in the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: We can't help you debug a regex if you don't show us your real input. My previous comment explains the problem with what you've actually shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your regex to

```
var cursodec = /\>\s([^#>]+)\s\##/.exec(dec);
```

to account for space on both sides

Comment: Thanks. I use the space here, not in my code, but this Regex solve my problem (after add the space on both sides).

Comment: If you wanted to account for any number of spaces or no spaces at all you could put a * after the \s